# Android SearchView open direction

Tags: android, view, searchview

I have successfully moved my menu items to the left side of the Toolbar.

But unfortunately when SearchView opens it opens toward left so it get disappeared while only the close button of SearchView is visible.

How should i force SearchView to open to the right?

Answer (score 0):

Whether `SearchView` expands to left or right is not easily switchable, it is a consequence of what `SearchView` layout is.

You can, however, try overriding the layout of `SearchView` in your theme. *I haven't done this myself, you may need to wiggle the layout a bit to get it right.*

Derive your theme from `Theme.Material` and override the `searchViewStyle` attribute with your custom style for search view:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchView</item>
</style>
```

Then, derive the custom search view style and override the `layout` attribute:

```
<style name="MySearchView" parent="android:Widget.Material.SearchView">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/search_view</item>
</style>
```

And finally, create your custom `layout/search_view.xml` to adjust the layout the way you want it. Copy over [the original search_view.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/search_view.xml) and make any changes you need -- probably change order of `search_src_text` ([line 79](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/search_view.xml#L79)) and `search_close_btn` ([line 98](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/search_view.xml#L98))

Don't forget to prefix all ids in the copied layout with `android:` (or not, if you're using the support lib variant, but that's another story, I'm sure you know what to do)

---

(*Marcos Vasconcelos*) This solution doesn't works prior of Android 4.0.

(*Ivan Bartsov*) Thanks for the edit, but it's not really true. Actually, prior to Android 5.0 (since it relies on Material theme, obviously) -- but it can be adjusted to be used with `appcompat-v7` support library, which makes it suitable all the way down to 2.1. The OP obviously uses either Android 5.0+ or the support lib -- you may have noticed they're using [`Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) which is only available since API 21

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes I am using the support lib and i'm Targeting API 14. I'll check this and let you know.

Comment: One more question. Can i even copy all the code of support SearchView from source, including code and layout and make my changes?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari Yeah. You don't really need to copy the java source, just overriding layout should do. And with support lib, you don't need `android:` prefixes in ids or style attributes.